# Why does this EF query produce such crazy generated SQL?

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, database-performance

```
var statusId = db.WorkOrder.Where(w => w.OrderType.Name == "ReadAudit" && w.WorkOrderMapping.MeterOldTag == meterTag && w.OrderStatusId != 80)
                .OrderByDescending(w => w.CreationDatetime)
                .Select(r => r.OrderStatusId)                    
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

That produces this crazy sql:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Project1].[OrderStatusId] AS [OrderStatusId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[OrderStatusId] AS [OrderStatusId], 
    [Filter1].[CreationDatetime] AS [CreationDatetime]
    FROM ( 
        SELECT [Extent1].[OrderStatusId] AS [OrderStatusId], 
               [Extent1].[CreationDatetime] AS [CreationDatetime], 
               [Extent3].[MeterOldTag] AS [MeterOldTag]
        FROM   [dbo].[WorkOrder] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrderTypeKey] = [Extent2].[OrderTypeKey]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WorkOrderMapping] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[WorkOrderKey] = [Extent3].[WorkOrderMappingKey]
        WHERE (80 <> [Extent1].[OrderStatusId]) 
        AND (N'ReadAudit' = [Extent2].[Name])
    )  AS [Filter1]
    WHERE ([Filter1].[MeterOldTag] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Filter1].[MeterOldTag] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[CreationDatetime] DESC
```

And I'm told that its hitting the database pretty hard:

Table 'WorkOrder'. Scan count 30, logical reads 84403

Table 'WorkOrderMapping'. Scan count 9, logical reads 16516

The EF query doesn't seem that complicated. Is there a way to get the generated SQL to be more efficient?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this question. We don't have the DB model, the C# model or the mapping. We also don't know what you're trying to do. The only thing I would say is that you're using TOP/ORDER, which means that you will have to read ALL rows of the `WorkOrder` table for sure. The performance hit most likely comes from that rather than from the "not obvious to humans" query. Just for fun, remove the `OrderByDescending` and check the performance (the result will not correspond to what you want, but I just want to illustrate my point.)

Comment: There is nothing "crazy" about that statement. High read counts would likely be a sign of missing indexes. If this is an operation that is run frequently then execute that generated SQL in Enterprise Manager /w the execution plan and review any recommendations for indexes. When building apps /w EF, whether DB or Code first, you should run metrics based on real world usage against the queries EF runs to optimize indexing based on how your app is querying data. EF simplifies data access, but does not replace the need to optimize indexing for data retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

It is just how Entity Framework works.

If you want more control, you can write the query yourself via Entity Framework Raw Queries, see  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) and below a (not complete) example how your query might look like.

```
DbRawSqlQuery<Int32> query = db.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>("SELECT OrderStatusId FROM ... ");
var statusId = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

---

**Edit:**

Also have a look at the actual query plan that gets executed for this query in order to find if whether the appropriate indexes are present on the tables involved.

Consider moving the constants `RealAudit`and `80` to variables, like below:

```
var orderType = "RealAudit";
var orderStatusId = 80;

var statusId = db.WorkOrder.Where(w => w.OrderType.Name == orderType
        && w.WorkOrderMapping.MeterOldTag == meterTag 
        && w.OrderStatusId != orderStatusId
    )
    .OrderByDescending(w => w.CreationDatetime)
    .Select(r => r.OrderStatusId)                    
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

By doing so, these will appear as SQL parameters in the query, something like:

```
@p__linq__1 <> [Extent1].[OrderStatusId]) 
AND (@p__linq__2 = [Extent2].[Name])
```

This allows that a single query plan can be used for all variations of this query, whereas now you get a queryplan per separate value of the the `MeterOldTag` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing "crazy" about that SQL Query is the predicate on MeterOldTag.  It's written like that because EF, by default, writes queries to emulate C# comparison semantics for LINQ queries.  If you want a simple equality comparison in the databse, set [UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for your DbContext.